# How to add export button in Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

I want to add export button in laravel backpack list page, i write  $this->crud->enableExportButtons(); in public function setup(), as mentioned in documentation but export button didn't displayed?

This is public function setup() function:

```
               public function setup()
                     {
                        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\Person::class);
                        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/lead');
                        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('Lead', 'Lead');
                        $this->crud->enableExportButtons();
                     }
```

i try to fix it by writing $this->crud->enableExportButtons();in protected function setupListOperation() but it is not working.

```
               protected function setupListOperation()
                    {
                        $this->crud->enableExportButtons();
                              .
                              .
                              .
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding enableExportButtons in setup operation is enough for showing the export button. If it's not still showing then try to clear your view.

```
php artisan view:clear
```